# Are there any free fraktura fonts available for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

Where can I find them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the `yfonts` package that provides several styles of Fraktur fonts.  It's quite old and stable and should be part of all the standard TeX distributions (I just checked it is present in TeX Live, but don't have access to MiKTeX).

Comment: yfonts is available in MikTex http://miktex.org/packages/yfonts

Comment: Thanks.  It seemed obvious but I was just too lazy to check it as I don't use MiKTeX myself.

Answer (score 7):

A good place to look for questions such as this is the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).  [This page](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/yfrak/) shows how to use a Fraktur font.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using XeTeX / XeLaTeX take a look at the "Unifraktur" project at http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net
Although the site is written in German language you might be able to find the "download" section.

They offer only 2 blackletter fonts, "UnifrakturMaguntia" and "UnifrakturCook", but these work perfectly with XeTeX.
(These are Unicode fonts, i.e. the "long s" (ſ) is positioned at its official Unicode position. Nothing more is needed for typing a text, especially all ligatures (which are quite essential in blackletter fonts) are automatically set by XeTeX, as long as you don't manually prevent this [wherever necessary] by the usual "no ligature" macro.)

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX font catalog has a [Blackletter section](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html).  Or if you are using XeTeX or another environment that can deal with TrueType fonts, take a look at Dieter Steffmann's [amazing collection](http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/index.htm) of free, historic, mostly German typefaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind installing your own fonts (see, for example, [Displaying medieval scriptures and neumes in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex/100943#100943)), one of the greatest sources I've found is at

http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/index.htm

You will find many, many varieties of fonts there, including fraktura, rotunda, textura, Schwabacher, and other more modern forms.

Other, lesser sources include:

http://www.morscher.com/3r/fonts/fraktur.htm

http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/BoereTudor.htm

and for non-blackletter

http://www.fontparadise.com/

http://4umi.com/web/font/hand/