# Changing document font to whole new font

Tags: fonts

I need to write a report for my work and I wanted to use our corporate type for this. Is there any possibility to change the document fonts to those customized ones? I've got them as TrueType fonts.

I started using LaTeX some weeks ago and already searched the web and tex.stackexchange for an answer, but either they where not satisfying or I've failed to notice them. I know it's kinda against the spirit of LaTeX to change the fonts, because of researches and stuff, but I would like to use the corporate fonts I've got.

Comment: Hi! Have you seen [XeLaTeX](http://tug.org/xetex/)? It allows to use system fonts inside LaTeX. However, you cannot use most system fonts as math fonts, you therefore need to find a well-matching math font for mathematics.

Comment: Lualatex also allows use of system fonts via the `fontspec` package, just as xelatex.

Comment: Have a look at this XeLaTeX answer to [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251).

Comment: If you have the TT or T1 font files, new fonts can be, with some difficulty, added to your LaTeX distribution. I can't say the technique is up to date (done years ago with MikTeX under W2K), but these answers show what I did for TT fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex/100943#100943 and for T1 fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106002/convert-matematical-pi-6-font-type1-into-vf-files/106077#106077

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have suggested, this can be achieved with XeLaTeX. For example, to typeset using the installed system font `Times New Roman` the code would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
<your document text here>
\end{document}
```

You also need to change your compile process (or reconfigure the build profile if you compile from within your editor) to use the XeLaTeX command instead of the PDFLaTeX command. Many popular modern LaTeX editors come with a built-in build profile to compile via XeLaTeX.

You can read more about `fontspec` in the [documentation](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf). If you need to typeset mathematics in your custom font too then you can replace the `fontspec` package with
`mathspec`, which is documented [here](ftp://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdf).

Before going to this trouble, you might find it worthwhile to look at the [LaTeX FontCatalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). Many popular fonts such as Times or Garamond have free LaTeX versions that can be invoked with a simple command in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll have a look XeLaTeX later on and hope it'll help my with my problem. :)
Actually I like the default LaTex fonts and I wouldn't go through all this trouble if we hadn't such a dumb corporate design manual and lucky me, I'm the only one using LaTeX at work, all of my colleagues use MS Word. :(