# Changing font on resume template

Tags: fonts

I am new to using Latex templates and I am formatting my resume using the below template. https://github.com/TimmyChan/data-science-tech-resume-template

I want to change the font to a standard PC font such as Arial, Tahoma, etc. But i am not able to fig out how to change it.

The current font is sourcesanspro and I am unable to edit it.
I have attched the code below for your reference.

```
> \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} \ProvidesPackage{TLCresume}[11/19/21 resume
> package] % Author: Timmy Chan % Assuming using "article" document
> class and letter sized paper. % FONT STUFF
> \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} %  Font encoding
> https://texfaq.org/FAQ-why-inp-font
> \RequirePackage[default,semibold]{sourcesanspro}
> \RequirePackage[10pt]{moresize} \usepackage{anyfontsize}
> \RequirePackage{csquotes} % MARGINS AND SPACING
> \RequirePackage[margin=.5in, top=.5in, bottom=1in]{geometry} % Set
> Margins \raggedright % left align no indent \raggedbottom % top align
> no indent % COLOR \RequirePackage{xcolor}
> \definecolor{highlight}{RGB}{61, 90, 128} % CHANGE THIS TO YOUR FAV
> COLOR https://g.co/kgs/aoqdi7 % LINKS \RequirePackage{hyperref}
> \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=highlight} % BULLET POINTS
> \RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in} %
> SECTION FORMATTING  \RequirePackage[nostruts]{titlesec}
> \titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{0.5em}{0em}
> \titleformat{\section}{\color{highlight} \scshape \raggedright
> \large}{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-0.75em}\hrulefill] % SUBSECTION FORMATTING
> \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{0em}{0em}
> \titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0em}{}[] % BOLD COMMAND
> \newcommand{\skills}[1]{ {\bfseries #1}} % SUBTEXT
> \newcommand{\subtext}[1]{\textit{#1}\par\vspace{-.75em}} % tighter
> spacing than itemize \setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}
> \newenvironment{zitemize}{ \begin{itemize} \itemsep 0pt \parskip 0pt
> \parsep 1pt} {\end{itemize}\vspace{-.5em}} % NO PAGE NUMBER
> \pagenumbering{gobble} % SUBFILES IMPORTING
> \RequirePackage{standalone} % FOR TEMPLATE FILLER
> \RequirePackage[english]{babel} \RequirePackage{blindtext}% Filler
> Text
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please copy and paste your source code into a code block, rather than posting a screenshot?

Comment: Please don't add `>` in front of each code line. We need code, that could be tested without any change, because every needed change would be a guess and so could lead to unrelated code. Try to add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) starting with `\documentclass`, using only those code in the document preamble, the is really needed to reproduce the problem, also containing `\begin{document}` and a body needed to reproduce the problem, and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Using PDFLaTeX (as it seems, because you have `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}`), changing the font is usually done by loading a font package. With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX it would be much easier because of package `fontspec`, which allows to load such fonts using, e.g., `\setsansfont{Arial}`. See also, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117573