# Trying to use a particular font

Tags: fonts

I want to use Dominican/Butterbrotpapier/blackletter fonts as shown 
in [Simulate printing imperfections and defects with TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex), however, there is no latex file so as to replicate similar results.

I will appreciate any help or guidance that you can provide.

What I could claim is that I tried to ask the similar question to the creator of the post, nonetheless, I have not been successful.

P.S. Laptop is running a 32bits Ubuntu 12.04 OS

Comment: Compile with XeLaTeX, load `fontspec` package, and `\setmainfont{Dominican}` should do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: If you can't use XeLaTeX, these are related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106002/convert-matematical-pi-6-font-type1-into-vf-files/106077#106077 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex/100943#100943. **WARNING:** the methods described there were for a Windows2000 system, and likely don't work without significant revisions.  And they required some hand holding.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document ⇒ the XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX answer.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, Xe/LuaTeX will offer you the most flexible solution. However, at least blackletter fonts have support in (pdf)TeX. The CTAN font catalogue features a [selection](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html).

For example, the following are included in TeX Live with support for (pdf)TeX:

[image: blackletter fonts in TeX Live]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{egothic,pgothic}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\newcommand*{\myalpha}{\noindent ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\\The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\section*{Early Gothic}
{\egothfamily \myalpha}
\section*{Gothic Textura Prescius}
{\pgothfamily \myalpha}
\section*{Gotik}
{\gothfamily \myalpha}
\section*{Fraktur}
{\frakfamily \myalpha}
\section*{Schwabacher}
{\swabfamily \myalpha}
\end{document}
```