# Create custom font package for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, tools

Can I create a custom package for LaTeX, that provides a custom font?

There a packages like [`paratype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paratype) or [`droid`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/droid). I can just type `\usepackage{droid}` and it works!

Is there tools to convert OTF/TTF fonts in LaTeX-format? I need to use [Bitter](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bitter) font in my document. I know, I can just use XeLaTeX with any installed font, but I must use pdflatex for various reasons.

(If it matters, I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the question. If you mean, 'can this be done?' then, usually, yes. As to whether you can do it, that's a question only you can answer. If you are asking it, the answer is probably 'yes, if you are prepared to spend some time on it'. How much time? Depends on the font, the degree of perfection you require and various other factors. The possibility question is only 'usually' because some fonts may not be converted for licensing reasons or are buggy in ways which cannot be worked around without fixing the original font.

Comment: I had done something related tears ago on a W2K system.  Don't know if it is still relevant with newer OS and newer MikTeX, but here are the pointers.  For TTF fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex/100943#100943; and for T1 fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106002/convert-matematical-pi-6-font-type1-into-vf-files/106077#106077.  What I did was just an automation of this procedure: http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm

Comment: It would be *much* easier to use XeTeX or LuaTeX. What are the reasons that require the use of pdfTeX?

Comment: @jon, XeTeX/LuaTeX are great, but not fully compatible with cyrillic text: there a some problems with babel and BibTeX. PdfLaTeX doesn't have this problems (or at least have many tricks and known solutions), but has very limited amount of T2A encoding compatibles fonts.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Hopefully the situation changes soon....

Comment: Shouldn't you be using polyglossia with XeTeX?

Comment: There's always the `autoinst` programme. I don't like it much, personally, but it seems popular. This only works for opentype fonts, I think, and the fonts must be reasonably well constructed. (Any automatic process relies on things behaving as they should, of course.) The default is rather Latin-centric. Never tried to use it for non-Latin scripts.

Comment: http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php