# Does Anyone Know How to Replicate This Fraktur-Type Font Using Pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, typography

I would like to approximate as closely as possible the following typography I found in a book published in the early 1900s:

[image]

At first, I thought I might be able to make use of one of the fonts in egreg's answer posted some years ago to the following question posted some years ago:

[How to use Fraktur/Gothic fonts in text mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60360/how-to-use-fraktur-gothic-fonts-in-text-mode)

Alas, none of those fraktur/gothic fonts seem to be what I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This question seems more suited to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Therese The document I am working on is in LaTeX; and, as LaTeX has the capability of producing or approximating many fonts, I opted to post the question here.

Comment: LaTeX or not is irrelevant unless you have a particular problem using it with the engine you compile with. Your real question seems to be whether anyone can point you to a font that looks like the one in the image.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s off topic.

Comment: I can't find any that match, but there are some blackletter fonts here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-do-i-typeset-a-fraktur-x-that-looks-like-r/320407#320407 (Wallau may be closest)

Comment: whatthefont found a few plausible ones (not free) all of which would be usable easily with lulatex or xelatex (more effort with pdflatex)  [See this search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHBp3.png)

Comment: If you have more samples of the desired font, try answering questions about it at http://www.identifont.com/index.html

Comment: @Therese Does this question specifically relate to Latex or not? and if it does, then how is it ``off-topic''?

Comment: @mlchristians if the actual question is "how do I create a new font package for pdflatex" then it is on-topic, but a duplicate of for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314361/how-to-create-own-tex-font, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233303/create-custom-font-package-for-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex/100943. If the question is "what is the name of the font in my screenshot" then it is off-topic. If the question is "does this font already exist for pdflatex" then the answer is no (I think).

Comment: @mlchristians I haven't voted but it is very borderline on topic as the question is not really latex related it is just asking for a font that looks like the image. the software that you use to typeset wth any font you find doesn't affect the answer to the question.