# Trying to Imitate an Archaic Gothic Font within a Document Compiled with Pdflatex

Tags: fonts, spacing, pdftex, symbols, pgothic

**UPDATE:** I would like to mimic the following font which I believe dates back to the 19th century, for use in a document that compiles with `pdflatex`:

[image]

But here, so far, is what I am able to produce (with `pgothfamily`):

[image]

and with `gothfamily`:

[image]

and with `textswab`:

[image]

The three aforesaid `pdflatex` fonts can be produced with the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgothic,yfonts}

% To redefine the 's' into a "round" one.
\DeclareTextSymbol{\rounds}{LY}{141}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\noindent \textbf{\pgothfamily{\huge{Exercises}}}

\vspace*{25pt}
\noindent \textbf{\gothfamily{\huge{Exercis:es:}}}

\vspace*{25pt}
\noindent \textbf{\textswab{\huge{Exercis:es:}}}
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that the last image might be the nicest imitation of the desired one.

QUESTION: Is there a better way, perhaps, compiling with `pdflatex`, to imitate the desired font, other than using `textswab` with the redefined 's'? Or, might what I have shown be an optimal way---given the restrictions imposed. Finally, is there something that may be done to more closely imitate the 'x' given in the first image; which in my attempts, I recall having seen displayed as a capital from among the modern fonts?

Thank you.

Comment: how did you make the first image what font is it? If it's a different font the question is like asking how to reproduce a Times Roman heading using Helvetica

Comment: and `\Huge` does not take an argument

Comment: `texdoc pgothic` brings up a pdf with examples that look like your second: irregular spacing and that _x_. Notice the word "precious" on page 2 of the documentation.

Comment: @David Carlisle The word was copied from a book containing some Gothic titles; I was hoping to reasonably reproduce the font and thought of `pgothic`.

Comment: To learn more about that "x" style, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-do-i-typeset-a-fraktur-x-that-looks-like-r/320407#320407

Comment: Here are some font pointers that are similar, but not exact, to what you show: https://de.azfonts.net/fonts/typographergotisch-d/bold-21479, https://www.dafont.com/jsl-blackletter.font?text=Exercises, https://www.dafont.com/fette-trump-deutsch.font?text=Exercises, and https://www.dafont.com/hansagotisch.font?text=Exercises

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for these helpful comments.

Comment: what sort of book, on paper or a PDF?

Comment: @David Carlisle Copied from a book; I believe the font itself dates back at least to the late 19th century. So, likely not to be found on Font squirrel and the like.

Comment: hmm https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598712/1090