# How Might I Use This External Font with Pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, fontspec, external-files

This post adds another dimension to the question posed in [Trying to Imitate an Archaic Gothic Font within a Document Compiled with Pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632853/trying-to-imitate-an-archaic-gothic-font-within-a-document-compiled-with-pdflate).

There are other fonts outside of TexLive that seem to provide a better approximation to the image given in the above link.

For example,
[image]

is the output from the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\setmainfont{CloisterBlack.ttf}
\begin{document}
\Large
\vspace*{55pt}
\scalefont{2.75}{Exercises}
\end{document}
```

when I downloaded the font `CloisterBlack.ttf` from dafont.com.

However, the code uses `fontspec`; and so, does not compile with `pdflatex`, and thus, could not be used, as is, in a document that must compile with `pdflatex`.

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so, how, may a font such as the one alluded to, be called into a Latex document that must use `pdflatex`? Can the MWE code be modified to do this? Can `fontspec` somehow be used without resorting to either `xelatex` or `lualatex`; i.e., with `pdflatex` only?

Thank you.

Comment: while it's not entirely true simple answer is that you can not do that, certainly you can not use fontspec. Why can't you use lualatex?, there are very few pdflatex documents that can not be switched to lualatex with ease.

Comment: You can't use fontspec with pdflatex. You can perhaps (e.g. with autoinst) prepare your font  for pdflatex but this requires some skills and time (which why most people who simply want to use a font switch to lualatex or xelatex).

Comment: a truetype font can have thousands of characters (although that one probably doesnt) and can not be read by TeX, so you need to choose a 256 character subset and make a tfm metric file for that subset so that pdftex has a font format it can read then specify a mapping file that sets up the subset, there are tools that help do this, but essentially the answer is you have to make a pdftex compatible 8 bit font metric file first; you can not simply reference the original ttf. It is _far_ easier to use lualatex.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer. I thought something like that might be the answer. The font will work nicely for say, a title page, as I usually compile those with `xelatex`; as for the document itself, it sounds like I'd better think of something else. Thanks again for your helpful comment.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle for your very informative comment.

Comment: @David Carlisle And thanks for your `lualatex` comment about changing from `pdflatex` with ease. I will have to try that; but in case that fails for me, it sounds like a way to use the font *with* `pdflatex` is suggested by your second comment which appears to be above my skill level.

Comment: @David Carlisle Just to let you know---my 400+ page document compiled successfully with `lualatex`---even with `\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}`; which in the past, I have had to comment out when using `xelatex` to compile an index. So, I now expect to be able to use within it, the font in question "with ease." Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a truetype font can have thousands of characters (although that one probably doesnt) and can not be read by TeX, so you need to choose a 256 character subset and make a tfm metric file for that subset so that pdftex has a font format it can read then specify a mapping file that sets up the subset, there are tools that help do this, but essentially the answer is you have to make a pdftex compatible 8 bit font metric file first; you can not simply reference the original ttf. It is far easier to use lualatex.

Comment: Many thanks. I was hoping that you would post an answer based on your comments.